# How can we return the index of the last string or the base address of last string?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
 char *str[]={"we", "will", "teach", "you"};
 int count=0;i,len,m;
```

The sizeof(str) should return the value 18, while it returns a value 32 in codeblocks.
Moving forward if it returns the length of the string correctly, knowing the fact that this character array is stored in continous memory location, we can count the number of times "\0" appears as we traverse our array.

And this value would give us the index of the last string.
I tried in the following manner:

```
int len=sizeof(str);

m=str[0]; //assign the base address of 1st string
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
   if(*(m+i)=="\0") //compare the value at memory location with null
   count++;
 }
 printf("%d", count);
```

If somebody could provide me with an insight whether my approach is correct, or some other solution.
Basically want to find the index of the last string, or the number of strings present, when the number of strings in the array cannot be counted.

Comment: First thing, before I read your question: Is this about **C or C++**?

Comment: please do not assume multiple strings are stored in contiguous memory locations.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: There is no platform where the size is 18 - that would mean that a pointer's size is 4,5 chars.

Comment: If `str` doesn't decay, `sizeof(str)` should return the size of an array of pointers. It seems 8byte per pointer for a 4-element array in OP's case, which makes sense on a 64bit host.

Comment: @molbdnilo, 14 characters, +4 terminating nulls = 18 bytes.

Comment: @JPhi1618: `sizeof` does not work like this when used with `char*` arrays. Try to change "you" to "youXXX" and see what happens.

Comment: @ChristianHackl That's true... I was just thinking of a possible explanation for the 18.  Oh, you know what, I bet the OP meant, "It _should_ return 18, but Code Blocks returns 32"...  And he thought that because 14 chars and 4 nulls.  I don't think anything actually returned 18.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Yes, that might very well be. So the OP should probably clarify or fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that directly answers the question of "How can we return the index of the last string" so...

Given your example, you simply need to use:

```
int strCount = sizeof(str) / sizeof(char*);
char* lastString = str[strCount-1];
```

You can't walk each string to the end because they may not be contiguous.  You have to directly find the last index of the array using sizeof.  The contents or location of the previous strings won't help.

The reason sizeof(str) is returning 32, is because you are probably compiling a 64-bit application which makes each char* take up 8 bytes.  Four strings * 8 bytes = 32 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>  char *str[]={"we", "will", "teach", "you"};
>  int count=0;i,len,m;
> ```
>
> The `sizeof(str)` return the value 18, while it returns a value 32 in
>   codeblocks.

18 is impossible if your compiler behaves correctly. It's because the result of `sizeof` here has nothing to do with the total length of all strings. It returns the size of a `char*`, which is implementation-dependent, multiplied by the number of elements in the array. And 18 cannot be divided by 4.

Try something less confusing, something like `short arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`. It returns 10 on my machine, because `sizeof(short)` is 2 on my machine and the array has 5 elements, and `2 * 5 = 10`.

> knowing the fact that this character array is stored in continous
>   memory location

It is not guaranteed to be stored like this. Not at all, in fact. The individual string literals are in contiguous memory, and the pointers to those literals are contiguous, too. That's all. In other words, you could very well have a situation like this:

```
             +-----------------+
             |                 |
             v                 |
 "we\0"     "teach\0" "will\0" |   "you\0"
  ^                    ^       |    ^
  |                    |       |    | 
  |          +---------+       |    |
  |          |                 |    |
  |          |       +---------+    |
  |          |       |              |
  |          |       |        +-----+
  |          |       |        |    
Pointer1|Pointer2|Pointer3|Pointer4
```

> If somebody could provide me with an insight whether my approach is
>   correct

Your approach invokes undefined behaviour. You try to access memory after the terminating `\0` of `str[0]`, because `len` is greater than the length of `str[0]`. You also compare with `"\0"` instead of `'\0'`, which does not make sense, because the string literal `"\0"` is yet at another unspecified location in memory.

There are some other details wrong with your approach, but since it's based on a false premise, there's not much you can do to save it.

> or some other solution.

If the problem is really *"How can we return the index of the last string or the base address of last string?"*, then just remember the size of the array separately and do `size - 1`. If you are actually using C++, just use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Wow.  You actually took the time to make ascii art for it.

Answer (score 2):

> char *str[]={"we", "will", "teach", "you"};

this implies str is an array of pointers of type char.

so, str[0] points to we, str[1] points to will and so on.

str does not point to one contiguous string.

so, str[3] will point to last string "you".

Answer (score 1):

> knowing the fact that this character array is stored in continous memory location

You can't really do this.  Consider this code which displays the memory layout of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * spoiler = "you";

char * str[] = {"we", "will", "teach", "you"};

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf ("%p, %i, %s\n", str[i], str[i] - str[0], str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10b80, 0, we
10b88, 8, will
10b90, 16, teach
10b78, -8, you
```

The strings are not contiguous, they're being put on 8-byte memory boundaries.  And they're not even in the right order.

The computer makes no promises about the relative locations of strings in memory and it's even possible for different strings to use overlapping memory.

Answer (score -1):

Damn, it's been a long time doing programming in C/C++.

---***Note the below code has 'Warnings' especially deadly 2 ones by todays Standards***--

I couldn't fix them because I am a bit rusty in those concepts.I will have to go through them. Anyways you should be able to fix them if you have been playing around with C/C++ for some time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{
   char *str[]={"we", "will", "teach", "you"};
   char **ptr;
   int i,baseAddr,index;
   ptr=&str;

   baseAddr=(*ptr+0);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
     //printf("%u\n",str[i]);
      baseAddr=baseAddr+strlen(str[i])+1;
      if(i==3)
      {
        index=i;
      }
   }

   printf("Last Element Address:%d",baseAddr-strlen(str[index])-1);


   return 0;
}

//C++?
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  char *str[]={"we", "will", "teach", "you"};
  char **ptr;
  int i,baseAddr,index;
  ptr=str;

  baseAddr=(int)(*ptr+0);
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    cout<<&str[i]<<endl;
    baseAddr=baseAddr+strlen(str[i])+1;
    if(i==3)
    {
     index=i;
    }
  }

  cout<<"Last Element Address:"<<(ptr+index);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not even compile (at least in C++, don't know about C). Why do you post an answer if you are just guessing? And you don't even explain what you try to achieve...

Comment: Well this is a C only code. Lol, Why are you using C++ compiler?

Comment: The question is (also) tagged as C++.

Comment: C++ version added."Note: But has the same warnings(deprecated conversion from string constant to char* " Damn I forgot how to come around this warning.... you need to add 'const ' modifier somewhere but where I forgot...